# Concatanation of all csv files in one folder with pandas and directory that uses \ character

Tags: python, pandas, import

I wanted to ask for some help with following problem.
I have a folder with csv files structured in the same way:

```
DV00M270.MONTH_0.csv    169 MB  15.10.2020, 07:03:05
DV00M270.MONTH_1.csv    35.9 MB 15.01.2016, 06:11:47
DV00M270.MONTH_10.csv   58.7 MB 17.10.2016, 06:11:36
DV00M270.MONTH_11.csv   35.3 MB 15.11.2016, 06:07:39
DV00M270.MONTH_12.csv   33.8 MB 15.12.2016, 06:06:46
```

I would like to concatanate them all in one file using pandas so I thought about creating a for loop to import them all in separate DataFrame and then combine them with pd.concat([...]) method.

but I failed to get into the directory.... since I am working on windows I need to use '' marks.

```
files_no = range(59)

for i in files_no:
    Data(i) = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Raw Data\DV00M270.MONTH_' + str(i) + 'csv', sep=';', encoding='ANSI', skiprows=2)
```

basically the result of my approach is to get DataFrames: Data0, Data1, Data2 and so on till I reach end of range defined in a loop.

Could you suggest what is the correct syntax for concatanation of strings like that with **r'** as the begining? Now I get the error:

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Raw Data\DV00M270.MONTH_0csv'**

Comment: your missing a dot ".". it should be `.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this, but let's use a library from the python standard library that makes working with Paths and operating systems a breeze.

The idea will be to split on the filename `data_month_0` and return a dictionary with the file and the key as an integer that we can filter by.

i.e `{WindowsPath('D:/Users/datanovice/demo/file_month_0.csv' : 0, ...}`

We can then return a filtered list of dataframes and return a concatenated list of datafames.

```
from pathlib import Path 

def concat_range_files(src_path,range_nums):
    all_files = {f : int(f.stem.split('_')[-1]) for f in Path(src_path).rglob('*.csv')}
    filtered_files = [pd.read_csv(file) for file,num in all_files.items() if num <= range_nums]
    return pd.concat(filtered_files)
```

## Usage.

```
concat_range_files(r'D:/Users/datanovice/demo/',1)

#files out : 
[WindowsPath('D:/Users/datanovice/demo/file_month_0.csv'),
 WindowsPath('D:/Users/datanovice/demo/file_month_1.csv')]

   A  B  C
0  1  2   3
0  1  2   3
```

---

```
concat_range_files(r'D:/Users/datanovice/demo/',3)

#files out : 
[WindowsPath('D:/Users/datanovice/demo/file_month_0.csv'),
 WindowsPath('D:/Users/datanovice/demo/file_month_1.csv'),
WindowsPath('D:/Users/datanovice/demo/file_month_2.csv')]

   A  B  C
0  1  2   3
0  1  2   3
0  1  2   3
```